# PHP For Each Loop - Not Changing Object Value

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am calling a short PHP script with a JSON Ajax function. The following is the PHP script.

```
<?php 
// returns JSON
include_once("../sqlWorker.php");
include_once("../bkSupplyContext.php");
$helper = new bkSupplyContext();
$dbContext = new sqlWorker();
$resources = $dbContext->getFullSortedEntityArray("popeyesResources", "subCatID");
$returnResources = array();
foreach($resources as $resource) {
    $subCatName = $helper->getSubcategoryName($resource->subCatID);
    $newResource = $resource;
    $newResource->subCatID = $subCatName;
    array_push($returnResources, $newResource);

}
echo json_encode($returnResources);
?>
```

What I need the script to do is to grab the items from the database (the results are pulled into an array of custom class objects), change a property (subCatID), and then pass this to an AJAX function as JSON However, the changes are not keeping. I am still getting the numerical subCatID value instead of the name.

I have attempted multiple fixes. Initially, I did not create a new array, I just iterated over $resources, edited $resource and moved onto the next entry. However creating a fresh array and new object made no difference. I am still getting the numerical value. Additionally, I tried using an "&" before the loop variable ($resource). I am even tried just assigning a constant string value ("Hello") to the property and still ended up with numerical values.

I am quite perplexed and would greatly appreciate any help.

The ajax script (data[i].subCatID still gives me a numeric value).

```
$.ajax({
            data : "json",
            url : "/new/includes/ajaxScripts/loadPopeyes.php",
            success : function(data) {
                var currentSubCat = "";
                var popeyesResources = "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='editResources.php'><input type='hidden' name='tableName' value='popeyesResources' /><table><tr><th>Name</th><th>View</th><th>File</th><th>Save Changes</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";
                data = JSON.parse(data);

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    if (currentSubCat != ""
                            && data[i].subCatID != currentSubCat) {
                        popeyesResources += "<tr class='divider'><td colspan='5'>" + currentSubCat + "</td></tr>";
                    }
                    popeyesResources += "<tr>";
                    popeyesResources += "<td><input name='resourceName"
                            + data[i].id + "' type='text' value='"
                            + data[i].name + "' /></td>";
                    popeyesResources += "<td><a target='_blank' href='files/"
                            + data[i].link + "' >View</a>";
                    popeyesResources += "<td><input name='resourceFile"
                            + data[i].id + "' type='file' /></td>";
                    popeyesResources += "<td><button class='saveButton' name='saveButton' value='"
                            + data[i].id + "'>Save</button></td>";
                    popeyesResources += "<td><input type='button' id='deleteButton"
                            + data[i].id
                            + "'  onclick='deleteClick(this)' data-resource-table='popeyesResources'  data-resource-id='"
                            + data[i].id
                            + "' class='deleteButton' value='Delete' /></td>";
                    popeyesResources += "</tr>";
                    currentSubCat = data[i].subCatID;
                }
                popeyesResources += "</table></form>";
                $("#popeyesResourceContainer").append(popeyesResources);

            }

        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: try using 'var_dump' on the '$returnResources' and access the page directly, not via ajax, to see what are the results.

Comment: `$newResource = $resource;` does not actually create a new object. `$newResource` points at the same object.

Comment: Also, you don't need to use a reference when iterating an array of objects. The way you did it at first should have worked. Can you verify what `$subCatName` is right before you do `$newResource->subCatID = $subCatName;`?